# Is it possible to vertically align a :before differently depending on the size of the element?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a `:before` element that I want to vertically align differently depending on the height of the element it's attached to. I'm using it with `<blockquote>` however I believe my question applies more generally.

I have the following jsfiddle to illustrate: https://jsfiddle.net/06mf93kx/

Basically I'd like the `:before` element to be aligned to the top of the paragraph (as it is in the fiddle; the second quote is correct there.) However, if the paragraph is only one line, then I'd like the paragraph to be vertically centered with respect to the `:before` element, something like this:

```
+-------+
|       |
|       |  Pithy quote.
|       |
+-------+
```

Is there a way to do this in CSS without resorting to JS to measure the size of the paragraph and adjust the style?

**Some things I've tried already:** I've tried `line-height: 30px` on the `<blockquote>` and this produces the desired result for the one-line case, but of course spaces out the lines in the multiline case. I've tried `min-height: 30px` on the `<blockquote>` with `top: 50%` on the `<p>`, but this doesn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was Matías' [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) link that pointed me in the right direction.

Here's what I wanted it to do: https://jsfiddle.net/8utbj2o7/

Instead of `align-items: center`, I used `align-self`:

```
blockquote:before {
    align-self: flex-start;
}

blockquote p {
    align-self: center;
}
```

This makes the `<p>` element center itself *only* if it's got less height than the `:before` element.

Answer (score 0):

Since the introduction of flexible layouts, it's very easy. I've copied your jsFiddle HTML/CSS and changed the `display` to `flex`, and I've used `align-items` to center inner elements vertically.

```css
blockquote {
  margin-left: 20%;
}
   
blockquote:first-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

blockquote:before {
  content: url('http://placehold.it/30x30');
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  float: left;
  margin-left: -15%;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>
    Pithy quote.
  </p>
</blockquote>
<hr/>
<blockquote>
  <p>
    This is a long quote; there's a lady who's sure all that glitters is gold and she's buying a stairway to heaven. When she gets there she knows, if the stores are all closed, with a word she can get what she came for.
  </p>
</blockquote>
```

CSSTricks [has an excellent guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to become an expert on creating flexible layouts.

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for; it does get the upper short quote to look the way I want it to. But the longer quote should remain unchanged from what it was in the original fiddle; the image should still be aligned to the top of the long paragraph.

Comment: @ptomato Well, isn't just creating CSS classes that can be set to elements depending on their text length?

Comment: @ptomato Check my update. #1 blockquote does what you want, second has the style unchanged as you said... I'm not sure if this is what you want

Comment: @ptomato BTW I need to go to sleep, I'll check your comments tomorrow

Comment: Good night :-) That does indeed make it look like what I want, but I'm wondering if there is a general way to do it without tagging the paragraphs that are short. I'm trying to create a stylesheet that can be applied to all sorts of content. Going through and tagging every short paragraph with a CSS class would defeat the purpose; and also wouldn't work for different browser widths.